# How to implement Notification in the native android side while making a Flutter plugin?

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, flutter-plugin

I am working on a Flutter Plugin which requires me to schedule a notification on the android side itself. I am calling the function below

```kotlin
  fun setAlarm(){
    val name = "ALARM_CHANNEL"
    val descriptionText = "All alarms will be shown in this channel"
    val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
    val channel = NotificationChannel("CHANNEL_ID", name, importance).apply {
      description = descriptionText
    }
    val notificationManager: NotificationManager =
      context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    val builder= NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "SCREEN")
      .setSmallIcon(context.resources.getIdentifier("ic_access_alarms", "drawable", context.packageName))
      .setContentTitle("Title")
      .setContentText("Body")
      .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
    notificationManager.notify(Random.nextInt(), builder.build())
//        Tried this as well, not working
//        with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(context)){
//            notify(Random.nextInt(), builder.build())
//        }
  }
```

For debugging purposes I have not scheduled the notification yet. There are no errors shown in the logs as well, it just fails silently. I have my suspicion on how I am fetching the small icon. With all the other ways I tried to get the icon the app crashed.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very very silly. I had not assigned a channel to the notification